# Directory agnostic Apache mod_rewrite rule for web applications

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'm in the process of developing a PHP application but I have limited working knowledge of mod_rewrite which I plan to use to create "pretty URLs".

Whilst the application is in development I'm working on it in my `public_html` folder. At the moment I have an `index.php` which provides access to other PHP files like `customers.php` which takes an ID and looks for that customer's details in a DB and displays them.

The unprettified URL looks like `http://server.domain.com/~user/webapp/customers.php?ID=1` which I want to transform to `http://server.domain.com/~user/webapp/customers/1`.

I've written the following mod_rewrite rule which works to rewrite the `webapp/customers.php` to `webapp/customers/`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~user/webapp/

rewriterule ^customers$ customers.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

There is an obvious drawback to this (I'll worry about catering for the ID in the URI later for now). This is placed in a .htaccess and assumes that the application lives in `/home/user/webapp/` on the server.

This is clearly limiting and very inflexible, so I want to know **is there's a way of creating directory agnostic mod_rewrite rules** so that it doesn't matter where the application has been installed? I realise it's probably never going to be perfect as it depends on the server configuration but there must be a better way of doing what I'd like than the above?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for with "directory agnostic"?  An htaccess file in the same location as the web application will always apply to it (with an implicit `RewriteBase` of the directory that the htaccess is placed in), or mod_rewrite config in the main Apache config in a `VirtualHost` block.  Which part of the config needs to be able to change - the install directory, or the URL path?

Comment: Hi Shane: The install directory because I'd like end users to be able to install the application in whatever dir they like, so it could be `/var/www/html/` or `/home/user/public_html` but obviously the `RewriteBase` would need to work for both.

I've tried using `RewriteBase /` which works if the application is in `/var/www/html/` but not when placed in `/home/user/public_html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around I was able to answer my own question. When the webapp is installed it asks for a web address and a local file path for the app and uses that in the .htaccess as it's RewriteBase.

Answer (score 0):

For the use cases that you're talking about, having no explicit `RewriteBase` (and just letting it use current directory context, as is the default) should work just fine.

As for the ID conversion, something along these lines should work:

```
RewriteRule ^customers/(\d+)$ customers.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I have no `RewriteBase` I get `The requested URL /~user/webapp/customers was not found on this server.` when I visit `http://server.domain.com/~user/webapp/customers`. Permissions are correct because if I add `.php` to the end the script runs OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule /~user/webapp/customers/([0-9]+)$ /~user/webapp/customers.php?ID=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This should work!

(PS: I try to avoid RewriteBase because (believe my experience) you may get into trouble if yo have a lot of rules and you edit them many months later (= you don't remember there's a RewriteBase))